# Calculate the Ranks of Candidates based on Votes and Total Candidates

Tags: ranking, rank, voting, voting-system

How can I claulate the rank of each candidate when I have the total candidates and votes secured by each?

I've managed the percentage part, but calculating the rank has me stuck.

I'll be using MySql in the end for this, but right now I only need the formula or method to calculate ranks.

Id be glad if you could help with just the formula. Just like the formula for interest is `PTR/100.`

**Total Candidates**

```
5
```

**Total Votes**

```
75
```

**Votes**

```
Name    Marks   Percentage Rank(What I'm trying to calculate)
A       25      33.34       1/5 ->Rank 1/5 has the most votes
B       20      26.67       2/5 ->And so on
C       10      13.34       4/5
D        5      6.67        5/5
E       15      20.00       3/5
```

Comment: What language/technology?

Comment: I'll be using MySql in the end. But right now I only need the formula/method to calculate it.

Comment: I'll be happy if you could help with just the formula. Like PTR/100.

Answer (score 1):

There is a previous question on SO that addresses this, using MySQL and a ranking variable. There is some lovely stuff in the answers

[MySQL rank function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function)